# Como ordenar la respuesta de mi Firebase

Tags: firebase, reactjs, react-native

Estoy obteniendo todos los registros de servicio de mis usuarios y mostrándolos, pero quisiera definir el orden en que se deban mostrar. Para ello añadí un nuevo campo con el nombre `Order`. Mi tema es que no he podido hallar la solución del ordenamiento.

Adjunto código:

Obtención de datos desde la BBDD de firebase.

```
**static getAllServices(callback){
    let pathName = "/user/"
    firebase.database().ref(pathName).on('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
        let data = snapshot.val()
        let arrayOfServices = []
        if(data){
            for(let key in data){
                let obj = data[key]
                let name = obj.details.name
                let photo = obj.details.url
                let latitude = obj.details.latitude
                let longitude = obj.details.longitude
                let identificador = obj.details.id
                for(let prop in obj){
                    let services = obj[prop]
                    for(let sv in services){
                        if(services[sv].description && services[sv].rubro && services[sv].title && services[sv].image){
                            arrayOfServices.push({
                                userIdent: identificador,
                                userName: name,
                                userPhoto: photo,
                                userLatitude: latitude,
                                userLongitude: longitude,
                                userOrder: services[sv].order,
                                stateOffer: services[sv].stateOffer,
                                title: services[sv].title,
                                description: services[sv].description,
                                rubro: services[sv].rubro,
                                image: services[sv].image
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        callback(arrayOfServices)
    })
}**
```

Llamado a la función he inserción de registros en la lista:

```
 componentWillMount(){
     try{
         let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
         this.setState({
             uid: user.uid,
         })
         Helpers.getAllServices((services) => {
                 if(services){
                     this.setState({
                         dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(services),
                         rawServices: services
                     })
                 }
         })
     }catch(error){
         console.log(error)
     }
 }
```

Info de mi Firebase:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como tienes el *order* dentro del nodo *services*, creo que lo mejor es que ordenes el `array` de javascript luego de haberlo creado en `getAllServices()`:

```
arrayOfServices.push({
    userIdent: identificador,
    userName: name,
    userPhoto: photo,
    userLatitude: latitude,
    userLongitude: longitude,
    userOrder: services[sv].order,
    stateOffer: services[sv].stateOffer,
    title: services[sv].title,
    description: services[sv].description,
    rubro: services[sv].rubro,
    image: services[sv].image,
    order: services[sv].order
})
```

Luego ordenas el `array` con simple javascript:

```
arrayOfServices.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.order > b.order;
});
```

y listo, retornas `arrayOfServices`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, haz solucionado perfectamente mi problema!